# Buttons are overlapping using primeng

Tags: angular, button, primeng

I'm using primeng buttons and when I use two buttons inside a div, they are getting overlapped.

I tried using several css classes to have the spacing. But, I guess you don't need css class for the spacing between 2 buttons if you're using pButton. The styling is properly imported and I have also imported the ButtonModule of primeng, as I'm able to see the styling of the buttons.

Can someone help?[image: buttonoverlap]

Comment: How about adding markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a margin in the right and the left for the button tp solve this

style.css

```
.ui-button {
    margin-left: 0.25rem;
    margin-right: 0.25rem;
}
```

all primeng button has this class so this will affect all button in your project

Comment: Thanks, this helps. But, why doesn't the spacing come from the primeng styling itself?

Comment: @user2955641 this is not necessary the just give the option to us and onother way just add empty space between the butons even this what the did on the offical decomentaion page 

Answer (score 1):

Add to both your buttons style

```
style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:2px;text-align: center"
```

Happy codding!

Answer (score 0):

With me all other answers doesn't work with me.

`[ngStyle]` working with me, I just add it to the first button like this:

```
<p-button label="Submit" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit('save')" icon="pi pi-thumbs-up"
                    styleClass="p-button-success" [ngStyle]="{'margin-right':'8px'}"  ></p-button>
```